# How to activate .Net Reactor with license file?

Tags: obfuscation, net-reactor

I did purchase the license of the .Net Reactor, but I couldn't find any documentation about how to activate the .Net Reactor to Full version by using command line.

The reason why I need to using command line to activate is because I try to implement the process into azure devops pipeline.

I tried copying the license file to the install directory and specified -license but that didn't help

Thanks

Comment: [This page says](https://www.eziriz.com/help/ordering/register_online/) you need to go Help > Registration, use the Open File Dialog to select your license file, then restart the software. If you need to do it by the command-line then you should contact them directly.

Comment: It's a good idea to ask their support ;) After all, you've paid them!